# Fastify not working on Docker / Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean, fastify

I have very simple app that returns "Hello World" string, it works fine locally. As you will see from app code below it runs on port `4000`. When I create docker image and run a container, I can't access it from `localhost:4000` on my machine, but I can see that docker got to `node index.js` command correctly and app is running without any errors.

I also tried to deploy it to Kubernetes cluster, when I access load balancer ip I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. After inspecting this app through `kubectl` I can see that everything is running fine, image was downloaded and pod is running.

I'm struggling to understand what I missed and why it only works locally.

NodeJS app

```
import fastify from 'fastify';

const server = fastify();

server.get('/', (_request, reply) => {
   reply.status(200).send("Hello World");
});

server.listen(4000, error => {
  if (error) {
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.2-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/

RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Kubernetes manifest

```
---
# Load balancer
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: development-actions-lb
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-name: "development-actions-lb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-algorithm: "round_robin"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: development-actions
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4000
---
# Actions deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: development-actions
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: development-actions
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: development-actions
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: registry.digitalocean.com/myapp/my-image:latest
          name: development-actions
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
              protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-myapp
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First when I tried your code, I try it using a local docker but the behavior is just the same, so I expect it to be because of the fact that `fastify` by default only listen to `localhost`.

```
docker build -t development-actions:latest .
docker run -it -p 4000:4000 development-actions:latest
```

Inside of Docker you should mentioned explicitly `'0.0.0.0'` since By default `fastify` is istening only on the `localhost 127.0.0.1` interface. To listen on all available IPv4 interfaces the example should be modified to listen on `0.0.0.0` like so I change it to the following:

```
const server = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

server.get('/', (_request, reply) => {
   reply.status(200).send("Hello World");
});

server.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0', error => {
  if (error) {
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

The rest should be the same. To try it locally you can do it by using:

Reference:

1. https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Getting-Started/#your-first-server

Comment: That was it! Thank you, was stuck with it for a while

Comment: that actually saved my day!

Answer (score 13):

If you're reading this after 2023, the API has changed. Try:

```
fastify.listen({ port: 4000, host: '0.0.0.0' }, (err, address) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.info(`Server listening on ${address}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem setting host variable as '0.0.0.0' on `fastify.listen({port:3000, host: '0.0.0.0'}, () -> {})`
and everything worked fine.