# Kubernetes WebSocket service: Connection refused between pods using hostname

Tags: kubernetes, websocket

All of the links of google are pink... I've read almost every answer on here and consulted several colleagues and they cannot work out what is wrong with my config.

### My WebSocket server

```
// additional fastify websocket set-up - key point, is its running on 5000
const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen({ port: 5000 });
    console.log(
      `Market data websocket listening on ws://localhost:5000`
    );
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
start();
```

### Confirmation that this server works locally

I tested using `wscat` and it connects perfectly fine

```
wscat -c "ws://localhost:5000`
```

### Deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: market-data-ws
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: market-data-ws
          image: eu.gcr.io/test-repo/market-data-ws
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: market-data-ws-env
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: '0.5'
              cpu: '0.25'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
```

### Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: market-data-ws
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: market-data-ws
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
```

### My issue

I'm trying to connect to this service **from another pod server**. It does not need to be exposed via ingress.

Note: the pod will fail liveness probe, even though if i exec in and check the liveness probe it works.

#### The liveness endpoint works from inside the pod

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -o name | grep market-data) /bin/sh
curl http://localhost:5000/healthz
{"hello":"im alive"}/
```

#### ❌ Accessing the pod by curling the hostname from inside another pod = Connection refused instantly

```
> kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -o name | grep ui) /bin/sh
# curl the health check
> curl http://market-data-ws/healthz
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to market-data-ws port 80 after 8 ms: Connection refused
```

#### ❌ Curl the IP instead of hostname = Connection refused instantly

```
curl 10.104.1.61:80/healthz
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.104.1.61 port 80 after 3 ms: Connection refused
```

#### ❓ Curl the IP (but the wrong exposed port) = Connection Timeout after a few minutes

Because we get a time out here instead, this suggests to me that we were actually reaching our running container previously.

```
curl 10.104.1.61:5000/healthz
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.104.1.61 port 5000 after 129952 ms: Operation timed out
```

#### ❓ When I port-forward my local port to this running service port it works

```
kub port-forward service/market-data-ws 5000:5000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5000 -> 5000
Forwarding from [::1]:5000 -> 5000

wscat -c http://localhost:5000
> Connected
```

**Other things I've tried**

- Execing into the `market-data-ws` pod and using `wscat -c ws://localhost:5000` to check if its actually running okay - it is.
- Double, triple checked my containterPort / targetPort and colleagues have confirmed it looks 0okay.
- Tried `NodePort` and `ClusterIp`
- tried running my websocket server on port 80 and exposing that

### Other info

- Im using GCP GKE
- output of `kubectl describe service market-data-ws`

[image: kub describe]

Comment: Maybe it's because your liveness probe it's using another port, 8080 instead of 5000. Try changing it to 5000

Comment: @hackerman apologies - i think thats a leftover from testing it on 8080. The real liveness probe is on 5000. Also the pod is healthy, so it seems that kubernetes is able to talk to the liveness probe I defined.

Comment: As you can connect from local with pport-forward, your deployment is not the issue. Can you give some informatione about the pod from which you cant connect?

Comment: @Ralle I solved it! wow.. what a curve ball. The issue is that the web server I was using (fastify) by default only listens on localhost... wheras k8s has other ipv4 addresses that it will send traffic to instead of localhost evidently. I would love someone more knowledgable about k8s to explain that one to me. Check my answer below. But thanks for your assistance anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i have finally found my issue, wow that was the hardest problem in a while.

[Thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822353/fastify-not-working-on-docker-kubernetes) I was able to fix my issue.

#### Fastify by default only listens on localhost

I'm honestly not sure why this is not sufficient for use with docker + kubernetes, but I'm just glad its working now.

If someone is able to explain this in greater detail, I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Your service is accessible with kubectl port-forward, so service is working.

You say, your pod is not accessible from another pod.
Verify that the other pod is running in the same namespace.

The correct way of addressing the pod is:

```
servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

inside the container from which you can't connect, try:

```
nc -zv servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local port
```

should respond: open

if nc is not available, try curl or install nc.

Note in one of your tries you are using the clusterIp address. This wont work from outside the cluster.

Comment: thanks for your reply. all my pods are running in the default namespace. i have attempted FQDN addresss like you suggest as well, you can actually leave off the namespace.svc.cluster part if running in the same cluster/namespace so that won't affect it. as for clusterip - this is the intent, as i mentioned this pod is only ever meant to be accessed from inside the cluster

Comment: I just tried to nc the service name like you suggest - and there is no response, it instantly just exits the nc comand without output